# In RecentX, do tags disappear after a file is moved?

Tags: search, tags, recentx

I saw the program RecentX suggested in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/73979/i-would-like-to-tag-documents-notes-and-search-tags-with-logical-and-and-or/76058#76058  So I tried it out.

In RecentX, do tags disappear after a file is moved?

I just tried tagging a file   c:\users\user\desktop\blah.xlsx  then from the cmd prompt I created a directory and moved the file there. Then I looked for the files tagged with that tag (abctag), and no file came up.

I'm not sure if it had to reindex.. in which case, how to trigger it to do that.. Or if it sees when files are moved via explorer but not via cmd.

Comment: Have you tried asking their customer support? [Contact Us](https://www.conceptworld.com/Support/ContactUs)

Comment: @DavidPostill I will, but I think it's useful to have questions and answers documented here too, for the database

Comment: That's fine but given that this question is the only one tagged recentx it is likely that nobody else is using it ...